# one digit after a round number

Tags: c#, formatting

To format my numbers I am using this syntax :

```
move.ToString("+0.#;-0.#;0.0")
```

It works fine but if I have a round number it does not show the significative 0, example: 3 instead of 3.0.

Comment: is this close to what you are looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
move.ToString("+0.0;-0.0;0.0")
```